# Why Won't P4 Submit Open Emacs for Me?

Tags: cygwin, perforce

This is very odd, and I think my system didn't use to have this problem. I'm on a Windows XP system using cygwin. I have the environment variable $P4EDITOR set to "emacs", but when I do a p4 submit, I get the error:

`CreateProcess: "emacs" ".\t10640t25.tmp": The system cannot find the file specified.



Client side operation(s) failed.  Command aborted.`

Same thing happens when I set it to vi (except the error is with vi instead of emacs). When I unset $P4EDITOR entirely, the submit info somehow winds up opening up in notepad++ for me. Really strange, but I can't actually save and submit the description I put in there.

It seems like the problem is with P4 itself where for some reason it can't create, or open, or save the tmp file it uses to store submission information, but what that problem is is beyond me. Any ideas how to get p4 to open stuff in Emacs again, or at least to let me submit stuff somehow in command line? I'm pretty stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured this out. Apparently Perforce has a special client for cygwin. I downloaded it from http://www.perforce.com/perforce/downloads/otherlist.html and replaced the p4.exe in my program files with it, and everything now works wonderfully. If anyone else has cygwin/p4 issues, I strongly recommend getting the cygwin client.

Comment: That makes sense. On further thought, the problem was that P4 passes a DOS path down to Cygwin emacs. While Cygwin generally does support DOS paths, emacs does a bit of its own path parsing and decided that `C:\tmp\bla` is a relative path as it doesn't start with a `/`. Hence it tried to access a different file from P4. `nano` might have worked.

Answer (score 0):

For a while, Cygwin's default `~/.bashrc` unset the TMP and TEMP variables to address an issue with patched files inheriting unwanted permissions from the default Windows temporary directory. Turned out that that can greatly confuse non-Cygwin program that (somewhat wrongly) expect those variables to always be set. Looks like P4 is one of them. So just edit your `~/.bashrc` to take out the problematic line.

Comment: Hmm, I tried setting both to /tmp and to /cygdrive/c/temp (I created that folder just to test), but both times I still got errors along the lines of:

open for write: C:\temp\t9512t7.tmp: The system cannot find the path specified.

Is there maybe a setting I need to change in P4 for cygwin, or something?

Comment: I don't know. I'd still try not to set or unset TMP and TEMP at all and leave them at their default values (`Local Settings\Temp` or some such in your Windows home directory).

Comment: Didn't help, but I think I just figured it out. See my next post.